# use of php array as per if else condtion

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on form validation. when I click on submit it give me valid output mean after checking error is not empty. but when I make array of that error it not works like same. Both methods are mention below. please help me to get solution..

```
$name = '';
$nameErr = '';
function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if (empty($_POST['name'])){
        $nameErr = 'Name is Required';
    }else {
        $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)){
            $nameErr = 'Only letters and white spcaes are allowed';
        }else{
            $name = $_POST['name'];
        }
    }
    //if (!empty($nameErr)){
    $errors = array ($nameErr);
    if ($errors != ''){
            //var_dump ($nameErr);
             var_dump ($errors);
?>
<h2>FeedBack Form</h2>
<span class="error">* Required Fields</span>
<br /><br />
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" />
<span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form> 
<?php
    }else {
        echo $name;
    }
}else {
?>
<h2>FeedBack Form</h2>
<span class="error">* Required Fields</span>
<br /><br />
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<span class="error">*</span>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php   
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your error variable *$nameErr* was initialised with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), and you should not compare an array with a string (not this: `$errors != ''`):

```
if (isset($nameErr)) {
    $errors = array ($nameErr);
    var_dump ($nameErr);
    var_dump ($errors);

    ...

}
```

In case of an error, your 2 *var_dumps* would output this:

```
string(41) "Only letters and white spcaes are allowed"
array(1) { [0]=> string(41) "Only letters and white spcaes are allowed" }
```

It is expected that the second has the additional array wrapper, but for the rest they are the same.